# Manually restrict a page with Simple Membership Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, membership

I am using the plugin Simple Membership so users can become members of my site and access members only content.
I am also using the Events Calendar plugin with the Community Events add-on so people can submit events.
Bc the submission page is auto-generated and has no edit backend page to normally restrict the content I cannot make it so only members can access this page.

Is there a way to manually add a page to restrict it to members with this plugin or a line of code someone can recommend to make the restriction?

Answer (score 0):

I know this response is super late lol, but this plugin will solve the problem if you use Woocommerce.

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-membership/8746370

I had the exact same issue. What I did was restrict the URL. For example, my url was domain.com/events/community/add. So if someone didn't purchase my membership and tried to go to that URL, they would not be able to.

Hopefully you found an answer by now, but ya never know if there might be something better!

Comment: Thanks I think our solution for this was to have two separate navs.  One for non-members and one for regular members.  So whenever someone became a member or logged in the members nav would generate